# html: How to display/toggle a table after a button is clicked

Tags: html

I am currently trying to display/toggle a table once a button is clicked. When this table appears on the page, all previously loaded tables should remain visible.

Once the button is clicked, the variable called proceed is initialized. The table is displayed based on a conditional "if than" statement that is dependent on variable proceed.
Below is a snippet of the actual html script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.w3-button {width:150px;}
</style>
<body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script>
      var proceed = "";
  </script>
  
  <input type="button" class="w3-button w3-white w3-small w3-border w3-border-green w3-round-large" value="Recommend" onclick="display()">
  
  <script>
    function display() {
      alert("Hello world!");
      var proceed = "proceed";
    }
  </script>
  
  {% if proceed == "proceed"  %}
  <body>
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4>Recommended products</h4>
      <p>List of products recommended for this client:</p>
       <table class="w3-table-all w3-tiny">
            <tr>
                <th>Recommendations</th>                
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Product</td>                
            </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </body>
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Using the above code ( when the html script is called in a python flask api), table does not display once the button is clicked.

When the *if then* condition `{% if proceed == "proceed"  %}` is replaced with `{% if 1 == 1  %}` , the table is displayed ( when the html script is called in a python flask api). This implies that the variable proceed is not being set to "proceed" since `{% if proceed == "proceed"  %}` is always false when the button is clicked. Why is the variable proceed not being updated and how can one rectify the code to display the table?

NB: To test this snippet code above, kindly copy code and paste in https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_buttons_colors

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? because this not just an `html` question.

Comment: I am using python 3.7 to develop the flask-api

Comment: The syntax looks like Django. If so - that if-statement is executed server side while the javascript is executed in the browser. Thus serverside does not know of the variable `proceed`.

Comment: This is the example I am referring to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_button.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code - once button clicked table is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.w3-button {width:150px;}
</style>
<body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <style>
      #myDIV{ display:none; }
  </style>  
  <button class="w3-button w3-white w3-small w3-border w3-border-green w3-round-large" onclick="myFunction()">Recommend</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <h4>Recommended products</h4>
    <p>List of products recommended for this client:</p>
     <table class="w3-table-all w3-tiny">
          <tr>
              <th>Recommendations</th>                
          </tr>   
          <tr>
              <td>Product</td>                
          </tr>           
     </table>
  </div>

  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will toggle the div which contains the table. An example is shown in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show. You can copy and paste the code above into the link and view the results.

Comment: I have updated the code using ids as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you could give a button an id and use document.getElementFromId() function to reference that button

here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="e">Click me</button>

    <button id="e2">Don't Click me</button>
    <script defer src="./e.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("e")
var button2 = document.getElementById("e2")

button2.hidden = true

button.onclick = function(){
    button2.hidden = false
    button.hidden = true
}
```

so the javascript file gets the button with the id of "e" and "e2" and runs a function that when "e" is clicked, sets the hidden variable for itself true and the hidden variable of the button with the id of "e2" to false

i think it might work if you instead add an id to a table